# Unit testing FluentValidation rules for classes with sub/child classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to write unit tests for fluentvalidation classes when the object we are validating has child classes that are also being validated.

As an example:
My class looks like this

```
public class TestModel
{

    public class SubData
    {
        public int SubDataVal { get; set; }
    }

    public int ParentVal { get; set; }
    public SubData Sub { get; set; }

}
```

My validation logic looks like this:

```
public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.ParentVal).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(o => o.Sub.SubDataVal).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

And when I write the following unit test

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_have_error_when_val_is_zero()
    {
        validator = new TestModelValidator();
        validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(model => model.ParentVal, 0);
    }
```

I get a "System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception from
**FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidatorTester`2.ValidateError(T instanceToValidate)**

(if I remove the *RuleFor(o => o.Sub.SubDataVal).GreaterThan(0);* line, then it works!)

Similarly if I try and unit test the actual child class with:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_have_error_when_sub_dataVal_is_zero()
    {
        validator = new TestModelValidator();
        validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(model => model.Sub.SubDataVal, 0);
    }
```

I get a "System.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type." from **FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidatorTester`2.ValidateError(T instanceToValidate)**

Answer (score 10):

You can unit test models and child models but you will need to change your validation class to use a separate validator class which just validates the child model:

```
public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.ParentVal).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(o => o.Sub).SetValidator(new SubDataValidator());
    }
}

public class SubDataValidator : AbstractValidator<SubData>
{
    public SubDataValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.SubDataVal).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

You can then write your unit tests to test each validator or both together.

Comment: That is true, and would allow the "ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor" method to work. Personally I preferred to write my unit tests in a different way instead instead so that I don't have to change core code in order to make unit tests work.

Comment: This isn't changing implementation just to make code testable - it is how Fluent is intended to be used, hence the presence of the "SetValidator" method

Comment: By that I meant we didn't follow TDD. we already have a complex object, and it is already being validated by one fluent validator, I didn't want change existing working code so that my unit tests would pass.

Answer (score 9):

I have come to the conclusion that for this ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor is just not capabable of dealing with subclasses, so have resorted to doing it manually. i.e.

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_have_error_when_val_is_zero()
    {
        validator = new TestModelValidator();
        TestModel testRequest = new TestModel();
        //populate with dummy data
        var result = validator.Validate(testRequest);
        Assert.That(result.Errors.Any(o => o.PropertyName== "ParentVal"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With MSTest and FluentAssertions you can write

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_have_error_when_val_is_zero()
{
    // Given
    var validator = new TestModelValidator();
    var testModel = TestModel
    {
        ParentVal = 0
    }; // You should create a invalid TestModel object here

    // When
    validator.Validate(testModel).IsValid.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here as I did.

As all rules are executed during the Validation you need to set the whole model to reasonable values.

With current version you can do following:

```
//using FluentValidation;
//using FluentValidation.TestHelper;

[Fact]
public void Should_have_error_when_val_is_zero()
{
  var validator = new TestModelValidator();
  var model = new TestModel()
  {
    ParentVal = 0,
    Sub = new TestModel.SubData()
  };

  var result = validator.TestValidate(model);

  result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(model => model.ParentVal);
  //result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(nameof(TestModel.ParentVal));
}
```